# Differentiate joint cumulative distribution function

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

I have probability $P(X-a>Y)$ and I get CDF function as following (no explicit PDF form was given), and $F(a)$and $f(x,y)$ are CDF and PDF funtions, respectively.
$$F(a)=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\int^\infty_{y+a} f(x,y) dx dy$$
And I derive this one (hopefully what I have done is correct)
Lastly, I need to differentiate $F(a)$ with respect to $a$, but I haven't got any clue.

Please give me some hint or solution to this differentiation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) should be sufficient

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use Leibniz interal rule. If you do not mind, can you please check if what I have done is correct? $$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int ^\infty _ {-\infty} \int ^\infty _{y-a} f(x,y) dxdy=\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int ^\infty _ {-\infty} dy \int ^\infty _{y-a} f(x,y) dx$$ $$=\int ^\infty _ {-\infty} dy [\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int ^\infty _{y-a} f(x,y) dx]$$

Comment: $$=\int ^\infty _ {-\infty} dy [f(x,y)\frac{\partial \infty}{\partial a} - f(x,y)\frac{\partial {y-a}}{\partial a} + \int ^\infty _{y-a} \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial a} dx  ]$$ $$=\int ^\infty _ {-\infty} dy[f(x,y)]=\int ^\infty _ {-\infty} f(x,y)dy=f_X(x)$$